# How to setup Microsoft Remote Desktop?

Tags: networking, windows-8, android, windows-8.1, remote-control

I'm trying to establish a connection between [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.rdc.android) and my Win 8.1 Pro PC, but every guide I've found so far skip steps such as what to put under **PC name** or under **Gateway**. Also, should the **User name** be my email or something else?

I've also no idea how to find or add a user in the step 6 of [this guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn473007.aspx) because the only location listed is my PC and I don't even know what am I supposed to search for. I'm not even sure whether I *have* to add a user or this is an step I can skip.

A comprehensive guide for people without experience in networking would be highly appreciated.

Both my android tablet and PC are connected to the internet through a home router, in case this matters.

Answer (score 0):

PC Name can either be your hostname or IP Address (local)

Gateway should be picked up straight away by the wifi if your are connected in the same network.

Username would be your computer name "\" user name.. e.g: MYCOMP\Administrator

Password: your password

Note, you also need to make sure you PC is set up for allowing remote connections to it, in your windows 8 system, hit the start button, type: "remote" click on the settings (underneath search) and choose the "Allow remote access to your computer".

Check the Allow remote connections to this computer, then click the select users button. If your username isn't already added put yours in. Hit apply then you are all ready to use the RDC onto your computer.

Comment: I have being using Windows 8.1 and on Username I'm using my outlook email address since this is the account I normally use to log in.

Comment: If you go to your control panel the user accounts, select your user account. Underneath your name would be your account info: e.g. COMPUTERNAME\my@email.com <- thats your remote desktop username

Comment: Again, the COMPUTERNAME was not necessary on my environment. I'm using android to connect to a Windows 8.1 machine just like @jsoldi. Please understand that this does not mean your answer is incorrect. I'm just trying to give him an alternative.